# Protractor scrollleft but class have multiple instance

Tags: protractor

I have an element with `class="objbox"` but this attribute have multiple instances.

The current code that I use for scrolling is `browser.executeScript('$(".objbox").scrollLeft(' + strPixels + ')');` but since there are multiple instances, it seems like it is getting the first instance and scroll was not successfully done to the target element.

I am wondering if it is possible to include the parent element on my code, or if there is a different work around.

```
<div class="dhxgrid2-wrapper">
    <div class="dhtmlxgrid-container   gridbox">
        <div class="objbox">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.

What you need to do is the following

```js
// Define the elementfinder of your parent, pick option A or B
const elementFinderWithParentA = $('.dhtmlxgrid-container .objbox');
// Or
const elementFinderWithParentB = $('.dhtmlxgrid-container').$('.objbox');
// The amount to scroll
const scrollLeft = 50;

browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[1];', elementFinderWithParentA, scrollLeft);

// Or making it more readable, make a function for the scrolling
// and pass it to the browser.executeScript

function scrollToLeft(element, scrollAmount) {
  element.scrollLeft = scrollAmount;
}
browser.executeScript(scrollToLeft, elementFinderWithParentA, scrollLeft);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: btw, the objbox was captured successfully, but the scroll is not working. I confirmed it by getting the attribute of the objbox.

Comment: Have you tried it with just your Devtools in Chrome through the console? Does it scroll then?

Comment: in console, it is scrolling fine, `$(".objbox").scrollLeft(800)` but it automatically use the 2nd element. On execution, nothing happens.

Comment: Then use [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) in your CSS selector. My first solution was to add the parent

Comment: yeah, the element was properly capture but scroll is not working.

Comment: it is okay now.